# capybara have_error message?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

And User clicks Start Now button
Then Expect page to have error message 'Your scan could not be completed due to a technical error. Please try again, or contact our support team for assistance.'
expected #Capybara::Session to respond to `has_error?` (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./Features/support/common_gherkin_then.rb:82:in `nil' Features/scanner.feature:172:in` Expect page to have error message 'Your scan could not be completed due to a technical error. Please try again, or contact our support team for assistance.''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add the ruby assertion code you are trying to expect the error on the page